# Maxed out charisma

Tags: creature-design, economy, sea-creatures, trade, sea

The Feridians, marine fauna, kings of the ocean and for centuries unmatched with no predators and capable of eating and surviving on any source of food, even plankton.

This thing evolved perfectly to eat and not get eaten.

Thus the only remaining pressure for evolution was sexual selection.

Eventually Feridians with better and better courting skills produced more offsprings.

Feridians evolved language and society not to survive the harash environments but to have more sex. They are not really inventive when it comes to building stuff, but they are genius pick up artists and incredibly proficient at flirting and with an unmatched array of seduction methods.

Humans males who can be identified as "the average guy" have 4 to 6 different sexual partners in their entire lifetime, and sometimes those partners are females!

In contrast with the average everyday mediocre male feridian which has 4 to 6 sexual partners per day, of which most of them are actually female partners!

One could say Humans have high general intelligence but low social intelligence, they have more wars than sex..probably they are so violent cause they are frustrated sexually...poor naked apes.

Feridians are real  alpha chads, they solve every conflict with their genitals.  (Yes every war can be solved with sex, you just need the right methods and right amount of immagination)

Feridians do not have hands,and look like really big and colourfull fish, about the size of a hippo. They have social structures, verbal language, sign language and written language using peddles arranged in the sand.

Feridians are not keen on having sex with humans, that's kinda gross and also taboo, even if flirting and screwing is their best skill. So what other services may the feridians sell to humans in exchange for various favours and items?

Comment: [(...) sex with 4-6 different people during their entire lifetime.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWjLPIWdDws)

Comment: Are they a mostly female race, if most of them have sex with mostly women?

Comment: @NepeneNep i mentioned average human males,  and by comparisom I meant male feridians too...gotta specify, will edit.

Comment: Do their social skills extend to areas outside sex?

Comment: @NepeneNep they are smart enough to understand some basic logics but they are really slow when it comes to understing why a car moves or why the ocean has waves or why the sun rotates around earth. Their expertise is courtship and what comes after, their bodies and anatomy allow them to surive even if they lack  "street smarts"

Comment: "*Humans ... have more wars than sex*" OK, so the scenario is **HIGH FANTASY ALTERNATE UNIVERSE** fantasy? That makes any coherent answer very difficult, as we have no clue what rules your Humans operate by, or even if you could call them Human.  (your humans are also abysmally bad at War, if they manage to have more wars than sex, yet somehow have not depopulated the species)

Comment: That was a joke

Answer (score 2):

Maybe they can give advice or training in seduction for humans as a paid service. Depending on where they live in the ocean, they could be useful to partner with for marine research, or maybe they could help clear the oceans of human-sourced oil spills or trash and litter (if that exists in your world). I’d also imagine skill at flirting could translate into general manipulative ability; maybe they would be talented con salesmen, able to sell anything they find in the ocean to a gullible human. It really depends how you want their species’ relationship with humans to be.

Answer (score 1):

/an unmatched array of seduction methods./

Many of these methods work because they are engaging and attractive to the potential partners.  Non-partners who perceive the world similarly might also find these methods engaging and attractive.  We are not sex partners for birds or whales, but we can admire the handsome plumage of a duck or the creative song of a whale.

The Feridians genius skills at flirting and picking up easily translate into genius skills at artistic endeavors aimed at humans.  Instead of landing a sex partner with their beautiful, funny, tragic songs and creations they are landing paying human customers.  It is not very different.

Answer (score 1):

### Couples matcher.

They could use their skills to match people with appropriate mates and help them pick each other up. This is something that a lot of parents will pay well for. Everyone wants their child to pick a good mate, but often your child makes poor choices. A feridian can help you find a good match and help them connect.

### Couples psychologist.

Relationship strife is a common issue. They could help mediate these relationships with their superior intelligence.

### Entertainment.

If they have sex that much, they are probably less squeemish about it. They can do it in public for entertainment.